# InputStream of each entry in a zip passed as a byte array in Java

Tags: java, zip, inputstream

I need the InputStream for each entry of my zip (contains various files and folders) passed as a byte array.

This is what I have so far:

```
private void accessEachFileInZip (byte[] zipAsByteArray) throws IOException{
    ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipAsByteArray));
    ZipEntry entry = null;

    while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        ZipEntry currentEntry = entry;  
        InputStream inputStreamOfCurrentEntry = ???
        zipStream.closeEntry();
    }

    zipStream.close(); 
}
```

There is a simple way doing this with a ZipFile instance by just calling `getInputStream("EnrtryImLookingFor")` like in this example:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("d:\\data\\myzipfile.zip");
ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry("fileName.txt");       
InputStream inputStream = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
```

Since I can't create an instance that easily, I'm looking for an other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close to.

[`ZipInputStream.getNextEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html#getNextEntry--) does two things : it returns the next ZIP file entry but it also positions the current stream at the beginning of the current entry.

> Reads the next ZIP file entry and positions the stream at the
>   beginning of the entry data.

So just invoke `getNextEntry()` and then you can use the ZipInputStream object which the read() method will read the content of the current entry.

you could write something like :

```
private void accessEachFileInZip (byte[] zipAsByteArray) throws IOException{
    ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipAsByteArray));

    while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        // The zipStream state refers now to the stream of the current entry
       ...
    }

    zipStream.close(); 
}
```